# R trying to replace a backslash with an underscore in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string:

```
\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\x9a
```

How can I replace it so that it looks like:

```
_xed_xa0_xbd_xed_xb2_x9a
```

using gsub in R? I've tried:

```
gsub("*\\\\*", "_", testString)
[1] "_\xed\xa0\xbd_\xed\xb2\x9a_"
```

to no avail.

Edit- here's the dput:

```
dput(testString)
"\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb2\x9a"
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a backslash and not an escaped character in the string? What is `nchar()` of that character value? Can you actually dput the character vector you are using?

Comment: that's interesting, nchar(testString) gives me "Error in nchar(testString) : invalid multibyte string 1"

Comment: Sounds like you're having encoding problems as well. Where did you get such a string? What encoding do you expect it to be?

Comment: twitter field, i expect it to be a string.

Comment: But what is the encoding of that string? Unicode? Latin-1? What OS are you using? You have a string with non-ascii characters and it's important to let R know what each of the bytes are supposed to represent. If you do `charToRaw(testString)` you'll see the value for each of the bytes (there are no slashes or x's in the string itself). If this is all new to you, you should spend some time learning about string encoding.

Comment: Ah! I see what you meant now. By just stripping out the non-ascii characters I was able to get it to work :-). Awesome :-)

Comment: Perhaps `gsub("[\\]","_",string)` would also work? The brackets identify it as a character instead of something different.